# SSE g++ compilation issue

Tags: c++, g++, sse

I'm trying to play around with SSE intrinsics.  I have made a test program that just adds two vectors with four 16 bit elements together.

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void test_vec_add(){
  const int length = 4;
  float product[128*4]  __attribute__ ((aligned(16)));
  _m128 x = _mm_set_ps(1.0f,2.0f,3.0f,4.0f);
  _m128 y = _mm_set_ps(1.0f,2.0f,3.0f,4.0f);
  _m128 z = _mm_add_ps(x,y);
  _mm_store_ps(product,z);
}
int main(){
  test_vec_add();
}
```

I'm compiling this code with

```
g++ -msse3 test_sse.cpp
```

However, I'm getting the following complication error

```
test_sse.cpp: In function ‘void test_vec_add()’:
test_sse.cpp:7:3: error: ‘_m128’ was not declared in this scope
test_sse.cpp:7:9: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘x’
test_sse.cpp:8:9: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘y’
test_sse.cpp:9:9: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘z’
test_sse.cpp:10:24: error: ‘z’ was not declared in this scope
test_sse.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test_sse.cpp:15:20: error: ‘test_vec_add’ was not declared in this scope
```

Its probably a really goofy mistake, but I can't put my finger on where it is.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that the program you compiled? I don't see a `printf` in there.

Comment: Just as a side note, you know that a `__m128` doesn't store 128 floats but only 4 (and thus 128 bit), do you? This has nothing to do with your problem, but from your strange array declaration it seems you're not aware of this.

Comment: @ Potatoswatter: Yes, its the right program, I just made a couple of modifications before submitting it.

Comment: @ Christian Rau:  Yeah... That was just copied and pasted from somewhere, I'm still trying to get the hang of SSE.  Thanks for the clarifcation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a simple typo.

The types such as `__m128` begins with two underscores. The functions such as `_mm_store_ps` do begin with only one underscore.

Comment: Damn. That took way too long to find that problem.  Thanks!